# How to fetch multiple documents within a single query?

Tags: sanity, groq

I want to fetch multiple pages within a single query.

My code is causing errors

```
const pagesQuery = groq`{
    *[_type == 'homepage']{slug},
    *[_type == 'faq']{slug},
    *[_type == 'contact']{slug}
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
*[_type in ["homepage", "faq", "contact"]]{slug}
```